# MySQL: Adding partitions for future dates

Tags: mysql, partitioning

I'm trying to partition an existing table (with existing data) using its `created` field. Is it fine to create many partitions for dates far into the future? Is there any drawback to this?

Since the existing PK of my table is just the `id` I altered it to include the `created` field so I can partition it by `RANGE`:

```
ALTER TABLE orders DROP PRIMARY KEY, ADD PRIMARY KEY(id, created);
```

Add partitions up to the end of 2018:

```
ALTER TABLE orders PARTITION BY RANGE (TO_DAYS(created))(
    PARTITION p001 VALUES LESS THAN (0),
    PARTITION p002 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2015-05-01')),
    PARTITION p003 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2015-09-01')),
    PARTITION p004 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2016-01-01')),
    PARTITION p005 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2016-05-01')),
    PARTITION p006 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2016-09-01')),
    PARTITION p007 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2017-01-01')),
    PARTITION p008 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2017-05-01')),
    PARTITION p009 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2017-09-01')),
    PARTITION p010 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2018-01-01')),
    PARTITION p011 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2018-05-01')),
    PARTITION p012 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2018-09-01')),
    PARTITION p013 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2019-01-01')),
    PARTITION pmax VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE
)
```

Is this ok? Or is it much better to wait until the end of the year before applying new partitions for the next year?

Answer (score 3):

- What advantage do you expect to gain by adding partitions?  I ask because there is no performance gain to be had, at least not without other changes.
- You need to include the "partition key", `created`, in all `PRIMARY` and `UNIQUE` keys.  Usually it is best to put it at the end.  (You did that.)
- Since many operations open all partitions (yeah, this is probably a 'bug'), it is inefficient to have lots of 'future' partitions.
- I recommend 20-50 partitions in a table.  Less is rather useless; more leads to other inefficiencies.

In my [*Partition Maintenance blog*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint) I list the only 4 use cases for Partitioning, plus discuss how to purge old partitions and when to add new ones.

Comment: This didn't answer anything

Comment: @user1143669 - The question seemed to be about creating lots of 'future' partitions.  The answer is "don't", with some reasons not to.  Instead, create only one, but don't plan on populating it; instead save it for the time when you nightly "build tomorrow's partition" fails to run.